# How to create a sliding window generator python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1]
```

How do you add this with a sliding window generator of 5?
So it would be 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 + -1 and then 1 + 1 + 1 + -1 + -1, etc.
I am trying to calculate them but i am unable to figure how to move my range every time it counts up to 5.

```
    for num in range(len(value)+1):
        print(sum(map(int, value[num-n_day:num])))
```

Where value is the list and n_day is 5

Sorry I meant I want to do: 
    0

```
0+1 = +1
0+1+1 = +2
0+1+1+1 = +3
0+1+1+1-1 = +2
1+1+1-1-1 = +1
1+1-1-1-1 = -1
1-1-1-1-1 = -3
-1-1-1-1+1 = -3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do this with a slice and a list comprehension:

```
>>> value = [0, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1]
>>> n_day = 5
>>> [sum(value[i:max(i-n_day, 0):-1]) for i in range(len(value))]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, -1, -3, -3]
```

Comment: i want the result to be [0,1,2,3,2,1,-1,-3,-3]

Comment: Thanks so much! but i'm new to python but can you explain to me what you did exactly?

Comment: I **slice** the list into chunks and summed them with a **list comprehension**.  You should search in the python docs for the emphasized terms.